# Log ports opened by an application

Tags: linux, networking

I'm searching for something like:

```
tcpdump -p PID        # But tcpdump does not know the PID
```

or

```
lsof -i --continuous  # But lsof just runs and exits, no «live logging»
```

to log which connections an application opens.

In my case, I want to find out to which port git connects when committing. This happens in a fraction of a second, so I cannot use lsof. If there is a lot of traffic, filtering by PID or process name would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `strace` the process.

```
$ strace -e trace=connect git ...

connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("<your local DNS resolver>")}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(<PORT>), sin_addr=inet_addr("<GIT SERVER>")}, 16) = 0
```

Comment: This works for wget here and (only as root) ping. But for git the only output is «--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---» (also without grep), any idea why this might be?

Comment: Also, strace COMMAND|grep something does not work since it will only grep on the COMMAND's output, but it works with an additional filter: strace -e trace=network -e connect COMMAND.

Comment: If `git` forks an additional process to do the job, add a `-f` flag to `strace` that. Yes, if you don't have the pipe redirection `2>&1` then it will only grep on `stdout`, which is the output of `COMMAND`.

Comment: That's it! -f did the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> In my case, I want to find out to which port git connects when
>   committing.

Why not:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
```

The default port is:

- `git://` - 9418
- `git+ssh://` - 22
- `http://` - 80
- ...

Otherwise, git will let you know which port it connects to when committing:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
git+ssh://git@git.domain.com:1234/project/repo.git
```

Comment: What if the program happens to use something other than documented or what it claims to use? (Unlikely to be true with git, but could happen in other cases.)